# Как посчитать, сколько тактов идет программа на 8085?

Tags: intel

В течение семестра задавали простенькие программки под 8085 типа:

```
KickOff 1000h ; Where the command list is stored

mvi b, 04h ; store the number that we square in reg b
mov a, b
sta 2000h
mov c, b ; copy to reg c - how long to loop
dcr c ; decrease c so that the loop works correctly

Loop:
add b ; add b to accumulator
dcr c ; decrease c
jnz Loop
sta 2001h ; save to destination
hlt
```

Теперь для всех программ попросили рассчитать, сколько тактов они идут. Тут-то и застопорился.

Для помощи в написании программ нам выдали таблицы вида:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|Mnemonic |Op|SZAPC|~s|Description |Notes |
|---------+--+-----+--+--------------------------+-------------|
|ACI n |CE|*****| 7|Add with Carry Immediate |A=A+n+CY |
|ADC r |8F|*****| 4|Add with Carry |A=A+r+CY(21X)|
|ADC M |8E|*****| 7|Add with Carry to Memory |A=A+[HL]+CY |
|ADD r |87|*****| 4|Add |A=A+r (20X)|
|ADD M |86|*****| 7|Add to Memory |A=A+[HL] |
|ADI n |C6|*****| 7|Add Immediate |A=A+n |
|ANA r |A7|****0| 4|AND Accumulator |A=A&r (24X)|
|ANA M |A6|****0| 7|AND Accumulator and Memory|A=A&[HL] |
|ANI n |E6|**0*0| 7|AND Immediate |A=A&n |
|CALL a |CD|-----|18|Call unconditional |-[SP]=PC,PC=a|
|CC a |DC|-----| 9|Call on Carry |If CY=1(18~s)|
|CM a |FC|-----| 9|Call on Minus |If S=1 (18~s)|
|CMA |2F|-----| 4|Complement Accumulator |A=~A |
|CMC |3F|----*| 4|Complement Carry |CY=~CY |
|CMP r |BF|*****| 4|Compare |A-r (27X)|
|CMP M |BF|*****| 7|Compare with Memory |A-[HL] |
|CNC a |D4|-----| 9|Call on No Carry |If CY=0(18~s)|
```

Столбец ~s - это сколько тактов идет каждая команда?

Comment: очень похоже на то, что s это оно и есть. Просто нужно подсуммировать для всех комманд, которые будут исполнены. Понятное дело, что для циклов нужно умножать на кол-во повторений.

Comment: запусти программу на эмуляторе процессора, пройдись в пошаговом режиме и поле Cycles сообщит тебе общее количество тактов.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это количество машинных команд, хотя для однотактового процессора(извините не помню какой 8085, но старый, так что скорее всего так и есть) это одно и тоже. Теоретически, в любом микроконтроллере должен быть регистр-счетчик, который считает такты, это необходимо для отсчета времени. Даже если нет возможности получить доступ к этому счетчику, вы можете делить системное время на частоту процессора. У вас, я так понимаю архаичный интел? Надо смотреть документацию, такой счетчик там точно есть, таблицу вам скорее всего выдали для самопроверки. Когда мы писали для MCS-51 в его асме была такая возможность. Может там есть что-то зарезервированное в языке с названием на вроде **TCR**.

Comment: Я тоже не помню, но 8080, который был ещё старее, выполнял команду за несколько тактов. Кажись за 6. 8085 -- это не микроконтроллер, это развитие 8080 в плане уменьшения количества напряжений питания и количества ног (если не путаю) за счёт мультиплексирования шин адрес/данные

Comment: А я и не говорил что это микроконтроллер, согласитесь что если такой счетчик есть в большинстве микроконтроллеров, значит и в достаточно сложном 8085 он должен быть.

Comment: А где такой счётчик сидит? Я что-то не могу представить. Всё, что приходит в голову -- это соответствующий счётчик в симуляторе (не микросхеме). Если Вы имеете в виду таймер (у микроконтроллеров их зачастую несколько), то в 8080/8085 он вроде внешний (я не помню, кто помнит -- пусть подскажет). Но чем ТС мог бы помочь таймер микроконтроллера, я понять не могу.

Answer (score 0):

http://pastraiser.com/cpu/i8085/i8085_opcodes.html